# Can I make Firefox 20+ downloader behave like before?

Tags: firefox, download

I have the impression that Firefox 20 is heavier (on an older computer with 1 GB of RAM running Ubuntu-Xfce) than v. 19. There may be small features that change the way it interacts with that system; anyway, subjectively I see a difference that I do not like. (On a newer system with 4GB I see no difference.) But I want to be up-to-date, so I will try to disable the most obvious difference: the way downloads look.

Can I make the download manager look like before?

(Is there a big change involved with 20+? Is  this just a false impression?)